# Alamofire completion when app in background

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to create a background upload of images and video in same request. I created a custom SessionManager for background tasks:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.background(withIdentifier: "by.wink.citynews.upload.background")
configuration.httpAdditionalHeaders = SessionManager.defaultHTTPHeaders
let sessionManager = Alamofire.SessionManager(configuration: configuration)
```

And then I make the request with the following code:

```
func uploadNews(newsCreating: NewsCreating, progressHandler: @escaping (Double)->Void, completion: @escaping NewsCreatingCallback) {
    let parameters: [String: String] = ["text" : newsCreating.text, "category" : newsCreating.category.id]

    backgroundManager.upload(multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        for (key, value) in parameters {
            multipartFormData.append(value.data(using: .utf8)!, withName: key)
        }
        newsCreating.images.forEach({ image in multipartFormData.append(image.jpegCompressedData, withName: "images[]", fileName: "\(image.name).jpg", mimeType: "image/jpeg") })
        if let video = newsCreating.video {
            multipartFormData.append(video.url, withName: "video", fileName: "\(video.name).mp4", mimeType: "video/mp4")
        }
    }, to: URL(string: "http://api.someapi.com/endpoint")!, method: .post) { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let uploadRequest , _, _):

            // custom response for auto-parsing of json
            uploadRequest.responseServiceObject { (response: DataResponse<ServiceResult<NewsReporting, NewsCreatingServiceError>>) in

                // (*) alamofire completion, here is the problem.
                switch(response.result) {
                case .success(let serviceResult):
                    if serviceResult.success {
                        completion(.success(serviceResult.response))
                    } else {
                        completion(.clientError(serviceResult.errors))
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    completion(.error(error as! CityNewsError))
                }

                uploadRequest.uploadProgress() { requestProgressHandler in
                    progressHandler(requestProgressHandler.fractionCompleted)
                }
            }
        case .failure(let error):
            print(error)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that the completion of the request (*), is called only when app is in foreground. It seems that when app goes in background, alamofire still continue uploading (because of URLSessionConfiguration.background), but completion is called only when app goes in foreground again. I want to display a UNNotification if upload completes while app is in background. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Is your class alive when app is in background? The completion block will execute only when class where it's written is in memory(may be completion block contains weak self).

Comment: the viewController with the completion closure has weak self in the capture list, but this view controller is not destroyed when app goes in background. Morover, when app returns in foreground, completion is called and the notification appears.